# CefSharp WPF Error

Tags: c#, wpf, cefsharp

Have used CefSharp to use the chromium web browser in a WPF project. The build works as expected, but when published, the error received is:

***The invocation for the constructor on type 'CefSharp.Wpf.ChromiumWebBrowser' that matches the specific binding constraints threw an exception.' Line number '24' and line position '15'. IsTerminating:True***

Have followed the advise here:

https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/2030

Which unfortunately has not yielded any results, have also followed the read me here:

https://github.com/cefsharp/cef-binary/blob/master/README.txt#L82

The files exist in the published directory, but in the event viewer, the error:

***Application: APP.exe Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.IO.FileNotFoundException at CefSharp.Wpf.ChromiumWebBrowser.NoInliningConstructor() at CefSharp.Wpf.ChromiumWebBrowser..ctor()***

Any assistance appreciated, as am not sure where else to look to resolve.

Comment: Have you checked that all the files required by Chromium are actually being published?

Comment: Yes, all files, as advised have been added the the binaries, and are being published.

Comment: Why the downvotes?  They make no sense. +1.

Comment: Did you solved it? I have the same problem with version 65 on windows 8.1 x64

Answer (score 3):

You should install vc++ redist 2013(x86 or x64) on the target computer.
vc++ redist 2015 doesn't work.

Download available from here:

[Visual C++ Redistributable Packages for Visual Studio 2013](https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=40784)

Comment: Does not work for me. I already installed VC++ 2017 Redist, as my Visual Studio is 2017. However, I am still having the same error on runtime.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem after updating the NuGet package. I realized that my installer was copying dependencies from a folder named "Needed" where I had previously painstakingly collected all of the files needed to run the application (with lots of unmanaged things).  So when I ran the exe from the build folder it worked fine, but when I installed it, it crashed because all of the DLLs were for the previous version.  A quick fix for me was to just copy all of the contents of my build folder to the silly "Needed" folder I had previously made.

Hopefully I'll find this a year from now when it happens again.